# SQL - Structuring code for Group by and Sum in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I would appriciate any ideas on how to approach this problem/function in SQL code. Please see the attached image.

I need to Group the *AbsenceCause*, Sum the *numDays* according to each AbsenceCausegroup and get this displayed under each AbsenceEmployeeID.

The goal is to achieve a new table like:

```
|AbsenceEmployeeID|AbsenceCause|numDays|
|     081014002722|Children    |      9|
|     081014002722|Travel      |      2|
```

Thanks,
Joergen Mathiesen

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide your sample data as DDL instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
SELECT AbsenceEmployeeID,
       AbsenceCause,
       SUM(numDays)
FROM   que_ABSENCE_Days
GROUP  BY AbsenceEmployeeID,
          AbsenceCause
```

Comment: Thank you so much @X.L.Ant - I'll remember the DDL in the future.